# how to select a link from many button with same text one by one

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

There are many buttons with the same text i need to click it one by one while using while loop and it starts with the first one, second one, third one, and keep going on.

```
while(true) {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Follow'])[1]")).click();
 }
```

is there any way to change [1] into [2] into [3] every time loop executed so i can keep on clicking to the higher number and so on

Comment: int i= 0;
while(i<=no_of_links) {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Follow'])[" + (++i)  + "]")).click();
 }

Comment: would you mind to explain to me what is the function of [" + (++i) + "] does it add 1  every time loop is created

Comment: Yes it increments value of i by 1 in each iteration of while loop

Answer (score 0):

With your current method, you don't have an exit strategy for leaving the `while` loop. Probably an easier way to do this is to grab all the links that match that locator and then click each one in a loop.

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Follow'])"));
for (WebElement link : links)
{
    link.click();
}
```

Comment: well i dont need to exit the loop i will just turn off the program and this is actually follow button in instagram all of the link is not exist until you reach the end of the button and the page will go down and there will be some new buttons. you strategy wont click the rest of the unshown button

Comment: Well you didn't mention any of that in your question so none of it was addressed. The easy way to do that is to just scroll down to the bottom of the page before running the code in my answer. How to scroll down would be a different question that has been covered on SO before. You can google to find that answer.

Comment: the page will automaticaly scroll down when it almost reach the bottom follow button and i dont need to scroll i just need to add the number on ("(//button[text()='Follow'])[1]")) one by one everytime loop is executed. do you know how to do it?

Comment: You need to spend some time googling. You are asking how to increment a variable by 1 in a loop. It's pretty much one of the most fundamental things to programming in any language.